# Validation Summary For Ajax Call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

What is the best way to send back Validation Summaries back to the client when making an ajax call using jquery?

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to achieve this is to have a div inside your page containing a partial with the validation summary. When you invoke the controller action using AJAX it would return this partial and you will be able to update the summary. Example:

```
$('#validationSummary').load('/home/someaction');
```

where the action would return a view:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    return View();
}
```

and the corresponding view:

```
<%= Html.ValidationSummary() %>
```

This way the controller action directly sends the partial HTML that needs to be updated/substituted inside your page. If your controller action returns JSON you will need to accommodate in your existing JSON structure an additional parameter containing the list of error messages so that in the AJAX success callback you could update the corresponding DOM sections. A bit more work here but with things like [jQuery Templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) this might even be fun :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should return them back in Json. You can do this by `return Json("Your Message")`

If you're using ASP.NET MVC 3, look into the new remote attribute: http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2011/01/04/ASPNETMVC3RemoteValidationTutorial.aspx